# Fill area under the curve in a histogram

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, histogram, opencv

I'm using the method of the image to generate a histogram from an image, the problem is that I need to fill the area and I can't use the function fill_between because I don't have "x" and "y" parameters, I tried using "histr" and "color=col" as axis but the program crashed.

```
img_histogram=cv2.imread("567.jpg")
   colors = ("r")
   plt.figure()
   plt.title("Histogram")
   plt.xlabel("Bins")
   plt.ylabel("Pixels of the image")
   
   for i,col in enumerate(colors):
        histr = cv2.calcHist([img_histogram],[2],None,[256],[0,256])
        plt.plot(histr,color = col)
        plt.xlim([0,256])
```

[Final histogram generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOz9x.png)

I'm stuck and I don't know what to try, as I mentioned before, I tried to use histr and "color=col" as an axis to fill_between.

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgRFX.png)

Comment: please put the code as text :)

Comment: Ready! I'm sorry

Comment: `plt.fill_between(np.arange(256), histr, color='lime', alpha=0.3)`

Comment: Thank you, but it returns "ValueError: 'y1' is not 1-dimensional" :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fill_between()` method in order to do that.

```
plt.fill_between(np.arange(256), histr)
```

Comment: Many thanks for asnwering, but that didnt work, it throws: "ValueError: 'y2' is not 1-dimensional"

Comment: Can you add `.reshape(-1, 1)` after the arrange function or `np.array(histr).reshape(-1)` if this not works then please add the jpg file maybe I can figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help, i figured out how to extract the data from, `histr[]` is an array that contains the Y values, so now i can use it as Y variable and the array to [0,256] as an X, thanks to everyone.